# Application of Dominated Convergence Theorem, differentiation and integration commute

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f(x,t)$ be a integrable function of $x$. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ exists and  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \leq g$, where $g$ is integrable. Then we have to show $\frac{d}{dt}\int f(x,t)dx=\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dx$.

This is a problem from the book "Measure Theory and Integration" by Gar De Barra. I have taken $x_n \rightarrow x$. Let $F(x)=\int f(x,t) dt$ Then tried to calculate $\frac{F(x_n)-F(x)}{x_n-x}$.Using Dominated convergence theorem I have shown $F(x_n) \rightarrow F(x)$. But while calculating the limit $x_n \rightarrow x$ I was trying to use L'Hospitals Law. But I found that $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_n}\frac{\frac{d}{dx_n} \int (f(x_n,t)-f(x,t))dx}{\frac{d}{dx_n}(x-x_n)}$ ocuurs, and I cannot take the derivative inside the integral.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you considered using the mean value theorem for derivatives? And besides, I thought we need to assume that $\partial f / \partial t$ is dominated by an integrable function?

Comment: @KennyWong $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is dominated by $\left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right|$.

Comment: It looks to me like you're differentiating with respect to $x$? It seems more inline with the question to consider the sequence $$f_n(x,t) = \frac{f(x,t+h_n) - f(x,t)}{h_n}$$ for some sequence $h_n \to 0$.

Comment: @Tom you are right. But the same calculation occurs if I try to differentiate with respect to $t$ and I am stuck again.

Answer (score 6):

Let's consider
$$ \lim_{h \to 0 } \int \frac {f(x, t + h)  -  f(x,t)}{h} dx.$$

Since $f$ is differentiable w.r.t. $t$ (for every $x$), the mean value theorem for differentiation gives
$$ \frac {f(x, t + h)  -  f(x,t)}{h} = \frac{\partial f(x, t + \theta(x) h)}{\partial t}  $$
where for each $x$, the number $\theta(x)$ is in $[0,1]$.

So
$$ \frac {f(x, t + h)  -  f(x,t)}{h} \leq g(x),$$
which proves that the integral is dominated by an integrable function.

Hence, by the dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$ \lim_{h \to 0 } \int \frac {f(x, t + h)  -  f(x,t)}{h} dx =  \int \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac {f(x, t + h)  -  f(x,t)}{h} dx = \int \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}.$$

[Note that the dominated convergence theorem is usually stated for *sequences* of functions, but this isn't a problem, because we just apply it for every sequence $h_n$ that converges to $0$.]

Comment: you are assuming $\frac{\partial f}{ \partial t}$ is continuous, does it follow from the conditions given?

Comment: @Arindam It doesn't, and the argument is wrong as stated, but it's not too difficult to salvage this argument. You can obtain boundedness using the mean value theorem, and use that to exchange the limit and the integral, instead of replacing the integrand with a partial derivative and exchanging the limit and the integral afterwards. (On second thought, this may actually require us to bound $ f $ by a constant instead of any integrable function... I wonder if there is a counterexample to the claim.)

Comment: @Starfall Thanks very much! :)

Comment: P.S. @Starfall Do you agree that bounding $\partial f / \partial t$ by a $g$ that is constant in $t$ but dependent on $x$ is sufficient?

Comment: What is g(x) here?

Comment: @D.ZackGarza Assumption on statement.